# VBA Check If Sharepoint Folder Exists

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to determine if a Sharepoint folder exists in Excel VBA using the URL path and if not create the folder.  I can do this easily if I map the network drive:

```
 myWorkbookBasePath = "Z:Documents\Reports\2013\"

 If Dir(myWorkbookBasePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir myWorkbookBasePath
 End If
```

However, I can not figure out how to do it using the URL path.  If I use

```
myWorkBookBasePath= "http://sharepoint/Documents/Reports/2013/"
```

I get error code 52.  Can anyone tell me how to make it work with the URL path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a go

```
    myWorkBookBasePath= "\\sharepoint\Documents\Reports\2013\"
```

or

```
    myWorkBookBasePath = "http://sharepoint/Documents/Reports/2013/"
    myWorkBookBasePath = Replace(Replace(myWorkBookBasePath, "http:", ""), "/", "\")
    MsgBox (myWorkBookBasePath)
```

and in case of a Sharepoint site hosted using `https`

```
    myWorkBookBasePath = "https://sharepoint/Documents/Reports/2013/"
    myWorkBookBasePath = Replace(Replace(myWorkBookBasePath, "https:", ""), "/", "\")
    myWorkBookBasePath = Replace(myWorkBookBasePath, Split(myWorkBookBasePath, "\")(2), Split(myWorkBookBasePath, "\")(2) & "@SSL")
    MsgBox (myWorkBookBasePath)
```

MkDir in VBA can only access filesystem and does not understand URL's, so anything you can open in Explorer you can access with MkDir.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and Adrian's method did not work for me.

I found a solutions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-check-if-file-was-saved-to-a-sharepoint/971942cc-adcb-456e-93c4-6257ca119267), in Dighi's comment. It downloads folder to TEMP and checks if the file exists via Windows API.

Code copied from Microsoft Forum (Dighi's post), with slight change (popup to immidiate print):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Sub CheckSharePointFile()
    Dim fileURL As String
    Dim tempFile As String
    Dim result As LongPtr
    
' Set the file URL and temporary file path
    fileURL = "https://ABC.sharepoint.com/sites/Johnson/Macros/MyFile.csv"
    tempFile = Environ("TEMP") & "\MyFile.csv"
    
' Attempt to download the file
    result = URLDownloadToFile(0, fileURL, tempFile, 0, 0)
    
' Check if the download was successful
    If result = 0 Then
        debug.Print "File exists!"
    Else
        debug.Print "Error: File not found!"
    End If
    
' Delete the temporary file
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill tempFile
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```