# Check for access to Sharepoint folder/If the folder exists

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

Simple macro to SaveAs a basic excel file to SharePoint and then do a bunch of other stuff. The macro works perfectly when the user has an access to the specified folder FLUX PL.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://xxxxcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/CEEControlling/Shared%20Documents/Reporting/FLUX%20Analysis/FLUX%20PL/FLUX%20analysis%20PL%20" & Date & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

If the user doesn't have access (so he does not see the file), it half-saves in place of the original file so it is broken and I have to go to the previous version.

I tried include code to check if I have access/the folder exists in SharePoint, but it gives me

> Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number.

```
mypath = "https://xxxxcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/CEEControlling/Shared%20Documents/Reporting/FLUX%20Analysis/FLUX%20PL"
mypath = Replace(Replace(mypath, "https:", ""), "/", "\")
mypath = Replace(mypath, Split(mypath, "\")(2), Split(mypath, "\")(2) & "@SSL")

If Dir(mypath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Doesnt exist!")
Else:
    MsgBox ("Exists!")
End If
```

I also thought about `On Error Goto [label]` but by the time it gives me error the file is already renamed (and the original one broken).
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: First of all in which line do you get the error? And secondly can you provide the value of `mypath` after the replacements are done?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ In line:
`If Dir(mypath, vbDirectory) = "" Then`

The value of mypath:
`\\xxxxcorp.sharepoint.com@SSL\sites\CEEControlling\Shared%20Documents\Reporting\FLUX%20Analysis\FLUX%20PL`

Comment: I found this code here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693588/vba-check-if-sharepoint-folder-exists] but did not manage to get it working.

Comment: Hm that looks like your path is wrong or does not exist. Try to replace `%20` with spaces.

Comment: It still gives me error on the same line. Seems like the path is wrong. I don't understand why would the path work under SaveAs but did not work under Dir. 
I am not very experienced with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone would need it in the future, I got it working. I try to save it and if it gives me error I use `On Error GoTo` and open SaveAs Dialog.

```
    On Error GoTo savior
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "https://xxxxcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/CEEControlling/Shared%20Documents/Reporting/FLUX%20Analysis/FLUX%20" & Range("H2").Value & "/FLUX%20analysis%20" & Range("H2").Value & "%20" & Date & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False               
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Goto 0
    GoTo rest
savior:
    MsgBox ("You do NOT have access to the default folder on Teams:" & vbNewLine & "Controlling CEE >> Reporting >> Files >> FLUX Analysis >> FLUX " & Range("H2").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Select different location for the new trimmed file!")
    Filename = "FLUX analysis " & Range("H2") & " " & Date
    varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
                "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select File Location", _
                InitialFileName:=Filename)
    If varResult <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=varResult, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
    GoTo rest
rest:
```